# ERROR﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException, failure in SSL library?

Tags: java, android, openssl, retrofit

Using retrofit library in my Android app for a long time.
Now the app stopped working, with an error message:

```
ERROR﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb9753f20: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x97015926:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448);
```

I have information that the OpenSSL will update this week,
but I do not understand what this has to do with my app (which just has REST API, Retrofit, Java, own server). Here is my `app.config`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 34
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layout/navdrawer',
                            'src/main/res/layout',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:+'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:+'

    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:+'
    //compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'


}
```

Comment: Are you using VPN on your device to connect to this server?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set TLS ciphers and trusted certificates, as described here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS